# Center Div in Center of Screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, centering

I know it's been asked quite a few times here and on the web, but I'm having a difficulty with this.

I have a single div container in my HTML document. Just a body with a background and a div.

I'm making a "coming soon" page.
I want to center the container div to the center of the screen, so it'd work on mobile, desktop and any resolution.

I'm trying different code layouts, but I can't just get it right.

How can I do this?

Link to my code: [https://jsbin.com/puyege/edit?html,output](https://jsbin.com/repalukelu/edit?html,output)

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/alefhebrew.css);

 body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  background: url("http://lbscience.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Horsehead-Nebula.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#container {
  background-color: green !important;
  font-family: 'Alef Hebrew', sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#quote {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p class="bold">"אי-שם, משהו מחכה להתגלות"
    <p>
      <p>קארל סייגן-</p>
      <img alt="logo" id="logo" src="http://lbscience.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/LittleBig-Science-Old-Logo-300x90.png" />
      <p>בקרוב</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `left: 50%` on `#container` and then adjust your `transform` to account for this. You also aren't closing `<p class="bold">` correctly:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/alefhebrew.css);
 body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  background: url("http://lbscience.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Horsehead-Nebula.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#container {
  background-color: green !important;
  font-family: 'Alef Hebrew', sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#quote {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p class="bold">"אי-שם, משהו מחכה להתגלות"</p>
  <p>קארל סייגן-</p>
  <img alt="logo" id="logo" src="http://lbscience.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/LittleBig-Science-Old-Logo-300x90.png" />
  <p>בקרוב</p>
</div>
```